# Running unit tests for Puppet modules

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

I would like to add [RSpec unit tests](http://rspec-puppet.com/) to some Puppet 4 modules. To get started and confirm basic functioning, I would first like to run unit tests that come with standard Puppet modules such as [puppetlabs/apt](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt).

If I try running a specific unit test like so

```
cd modules/apt
rspec spec/classes/apt_spec.rb
```

I get only failures, and some of the diagnostic output seems to indicate that part of the Puppet runtime environment (such as module `stdlib`, which defines function `merge`) was not picked up correctly:

```
Failures:

  1) apt defaults should contain File[sources.list] that notifies Class[Apt::Update]
     Failure/Error:
       it { is_expected.to contain_file('sources.list').that_notifies('Class[Apt::Update]').only_with({
         :ensure  => 'file',
         :path    => '/etc/apt/sources.list',
         :owner   => 'root',
         :group   => 'root',
         :mode    => '0644',
         :notify  => 'Class[Apt::Update]',
       })}

     Puppet::PreformattedError:
       Evaluation Error: Unknown function: 'merge'. at /home/MY_USER/modules/apt/spec/fixtures/modules/apt/manifests/init.pp:50:14 on node MY_HOST
```

If I try running all unit tests like so

```
rake spec
```

I get this error message:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Bundler
/home/MY_USER/modules/apt/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Prior to these attempts I have taken those steps to prepare the runtime environment (on a Debian host):

```
 mkdir modules
 cd modules
 puppet module --modulepath=. install puppetlabs-apt # installs also stdlib
 sudo gem install rspec-puppet
 sudo gem install puppet
 sudo gem install puppetlabs_spec_helper
 sudo apt-get install rake
```

My question is this: How can I correctly prepare the runtime environment and successfully run the unit tests that come with a Puppet module from Puppet Forge such as `puppetlabs/apt`?

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45791768/4918 , where I fixed up the answer pointing to the new Puppet Development Kit.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to firstly ensure you have [Ruby Gems](https://rubygems.org/pages/download/) installed. Then ensure you have [installed bundler](http://bundler.io), which usually just means typing:

```
$ gem install bundler
```

Next, I assume you already cloned the apt module, so cd into the directory you cloned it in and then install your bundle:

```
$ bundle install
```

Now, there's a problem with that specific module you've chosen. When I try to run bundle install I get:

```
Could not find gem 'puppet-module-posix-default-r2.0' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
```

I am not sure what that means at the moment, and someone probably needs to raise a bug.

I expected to be able to work around it by using:

```
$ bundle install --without development system_tests
```

Even that is not working so I simply commented-out those groups.

Next, run the tests using:

```
$ bundle exec rake spec
```

That would normally run the tests. However, I think Puppet has broken the Rspec tests for people outside their company.

I am going to follow this up and come back and update the answer I have figured out what has happened.

I'll leave this answer here since it's still documenting the correct procedure.

See also my [blog post](http://razorconsulting.com.au/setting-up-puppet-module-testing-from-scratch-part-i-puppet-syntax-puppet-lint-and-rspec-puppet.html) on this subject, although possibly a little dated now. Let me know if there's anything I need to update.

Comment: Thx. Since it's unclear at the moment how the tests for `puppetlabs/apt` ought to behave, I'll post a follow-up question about creating and running a unit test from scratch.

Comment: I will edit my answer, I figured it out. I have an unsupported version of Ruby here.

Comment: Actually, no I didn't. Rake is missing from the Gemfile. Still puzzled.

Comment: Would agree based on that Gemfile that Puppet is using some custom gems from an internal repo for that module's unit tests.