# Correct way to start RSpec-puppet unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

I have created a simple Puppet 4 class and a unit test to go along with it as follows (after executing `touch metadata.json; rspec-puppet-init` while in `modules/test/`):

```
# modules/test/manifests/hello_world1.pp
class test::hello_world1 {
  file { "/tmp/hello_world1":
    content => "Hello, world!\n"
  }
}

# modules/test/spec/classes/test__hello_world1_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'test::hello_world1' do
  it { is_expected.to compile }
  it { is_expected.to contain_file('/tmp/hello_world1')\
    .with_content(/^Hello, world!$/) }
end
```

I can successfully run the unit test by executing `rspec spec/classes/test__hello_world1_spec.rb` while in `modules/test/`.

I would now like to proceed to a slightly more advanced class that uses code from another module, namely [`concat`](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/concat) (the module has arleady been installed in `modules/concat`):

```
# modules/test/manifests/hello_world2.pp
class test::hello_world2
{
  concat{ "/tmp/hello_world2":
    ensure => present,
  }
  concat::fragment{ "/tmp/hello_world2_01":
    target  => "/tmp/hello_world2",
    content => "Hello, world!\n",
    order   => '01',
  }
}

# modules/test/spec/classes/test__hello_world2_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'test::hello_world2' do
  it { is_expected.to compile }
  # ...
end
```

When I attempt running this unit test with `rspec spec/classes/test__hello_world2_spec.rb` while in `modules/test` I receive an error message that includes:

> Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to compile } error during compilation:
>   Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown
>   resource type: 'concat'

I suspect the root cause is that `rspec` cannot find the other module(s), because it has not been told a "modulepath".

My question is this: How exactly am I supposed to start unit tests, especially ones that require access to other modules?

Answer (score 5):

Install the [PDK](https://docs.puppet.com/pdk/1.0/) for your platform from its [download page](https://puppet.com/download-puppet-development-kit). Re-create the module using `pdk new module`, and `pdk new class`, or by following the [Guide](https://docs.puppet.com/pdk/1.0/pdk_generating_modules.html).

Now, I come to what is probably the immediate problem in your code: your code depends on a Puppet Forge module, `puppetlabs/concat` but you haven't made it available. The PDK module template already has pre-configured `puppetlabs_spec_helper` to load fixtures for your module.

To tell `puppetlabs_spec_helper` to get it for you, you need a file `.fixtures.yml` with the following content:

```
fixtures:
  forge_modules:
    stdlib: puppetlabs/stdlib
    concat: puppetlabs/concat
```

Note that you also need `puppetlabs/stdlib`, because that is a dependency of `puppetlabs/concat`.

If you want to explore more fixture possibilities, please refer to [`puppetlabs_spec_helper`'s docs](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs_spec_helper).

With all of this in place, and integrating the code samples and test content you posted into the initial code skeletons provided by the PDLK, your tests will all pass now when you run:

```
$ pdk test unit
```

Note that I have written all about the underlying technologies, in a blog post, showing how to set up Rspec-puppet and more from scratch ([ref](http://razorconsulting.com.au/setting-up-puppet-module-testing-from-scratch-part-i-puppet-syntax-puppet-lint-and-rspec-puppet.html)), and it still appears to be the most up-to-date reference on this subject.

To read more about rspec-puppet in general, please refer to the official [rspec-puppet docs site](http://rspec-puppet.com/).